# mongod console doesn't print anything

Tags: mongodb

It seems there are some problems when start the mongoDB server

But I don't see any errors on the console

## shell console

```
[14:03:58](~)
% mongod -f /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default

[14:04:01](~)
```

## mongod.conf

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Append logs to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logpath = /var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017
```

Comment: Can you check if the user has read write access to all the files given in the conf file

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412850/cannot-connect-to-mongodb-using-machine-ip

Comment: check the log, and report what it says is happening - you won't see errors to the console because your config has logging going to this file: `/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log` - any errors will be in there.  If I were to guess, it is probably a permissions issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12232668/1148648