# Mongodb Service won't start

Tags: mongodb

On my centos when I tried

```
mongdb
```

It starts.

But when I run it as service it wont start. What is the problem?

```
service mongodb start
```

http://screencloud.net/v/3weR

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232166/mongodb-on-ubuntu-wont-start-as-a-service-nothing-in-the-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in the logs. Why do you think it dosen't started? Its a demon process, it runs in the background.

```
service mongod status
```

may help you.

Comment: status: Unknown job: /usr/local/apps/mongodb/bin/mongod

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, run `service mongod status`

It should return `mongod is stopped`.

Now look in your mongo folder. There is probably a mongod.lock file in there. The 
only times I've seen this file created is when the power cord gets yanked out.

Remove the mongod.lock file:`sudo rm mongod.lock`

Start the service:`sudo service mongod start`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this command.

sudo rm mongod.lock

And

sudo service mongod restart

may help you.