# Can't start MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.10

I am trying to install mongodb on ubuntu 16.10, though it's not listed in supported versions.
I first got this error trying to start the mongo shell:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-12T11:15:00.464+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect 
to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: 
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused 
:
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I tried running `sudo service mongod start` but I'm getting `Unit mongod.service not found.`
I also tried modifying the mongodb.service file, checking for locked files, running repair commands and reinstalling mongo.

Logging files are not found in the specified location in `mongod.conf`, there is no `mongodb` directory in `/var/log`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232166/mongodb-on-ubuntu-wont-start-as-a-service-nothing-in-the-log

Comment: There are no mongodb directories either in `var/log` or `var/lib`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create mongodb service in systemd.

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

Content:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
[Service]
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
LimitNOFILE=64000
LimitNPROC=64000
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Auto start in startup:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

Start/Stop/Status:

```
sudo systemctl start/stop/status mongodb
sudo service mongodb start/stop/status
```

Comment: The mongodb.service file was there already. When i try `sudo systemctl enable mongodb` i get fail to enable unit: bad message.

Comment: This is the output to`sudo systemctl status mongodb`:

`● mongodb.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Bad message)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: You run "tail -f /var/log/syslog", and other console, run above command again and see output in tail console.